# trouble importing enums from google.cloud.speech_v1

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, enums

I have this code:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums
import os
import importlib

# Import the enums module from the google.cloud.speech_v1 package
enums = importlib.import_module("google.cloud.speech_v1.enums")

# Set your Google Cloud project and service account credentials
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "creds.json"


# Create a client for the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API
stt_client = speech_v1.SpeechClient()

# Transcribe the audio data
response = stt_client.recognize(
  audio=speech_v1.types.RecognitionAudio(uri="gs://focus-0/speech-to-text-sample.wav"),
  config=speech_v1.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
    sample_rate_hertz=48000,
    language_code="en-US"
  )
)

# Print the transcribed text
for result in response.results:
  print("Transcription: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dir/git/fp-scrapers/speech/1-STT.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums
ImportError: cannot import name 'enums' from 'google.cloud.speech_v1' (/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/__init__.py)
```

I have tried several ways to import enums, but none of them have worked.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

enums and types have been removed in the 2.x versions of the library

Mentioned in this [github](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#enums-and-types).Refer to this [migration guide](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/2.13.0/UPGRADING.html). You can refer to this [quick start](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-client-libraries) for setup instructions and an updated client library

**Before:**

```
from google.cloud import speech

encoding = speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
```

**After:**

```
from google.cloud import speech

encoding = speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
```